# Disable compiler warnings for a specific file in ClojureScript

Tags: clojurescript

I have a file that's defining functions like `map` and I'm getting [compiler warnings](https://clojurescript.org/reference/compiler-options#warnings) like:

```
map already refers to: cljs.core/map being replaced by:
```

So I'd like to disable this warning, but I only want to disable the warning for this particular file.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable compiler warnings for the whole project only. There is no fine control over that. But you can change your code so it does not generate this warning:

```
(ns testground.core
    (:refer-clojure :exclude [map]))
```

Comment: What if conflict is from a library and not file in project e.g.  
`abs already refers to: cljs.core/abs being replaced by: cljc.java-time.duration/abs`